# Do I need to bleed the brakes or overhaul?

Tags: ford, brakes, brake-fluid

My Ecosport has done just shy of 30k kms but the brakes leave a lot to be desired. The bite is not there as my friend's car has. If I apply the brakes it feels it takes time to come to the halt, while my friend's car stops quickly and his car has done 87k kms. Should I bleed them? Pads seem fine and car go for another 20-30k kms easily. Brake fluid wasn't changed by the dealer at 30k maintenance. Brakes have been this way since the day of purchase. Will changing the brake fluid will solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Some vehicles have much more sensitive brakes than others, so what you're describing may be totally normal.

But, you should err on the side of caution and do the following if you think the brakes are malfunctioning:

1. Visually inspect the brake pads and other brake components looking for any damage or other signs there is a problem.
2. Flush/bleed the system to ensure the fluid is fresh and all air is purged from the lines.

Comment: Yeah i am thinking of getting it checked and also I am going to get it filled with fresh fluid.

Comment: Even give it a formal brake test on a rolling road. @Voyager1011011 does your friend have the same model of car? When I borrow my brother's car, I have to be careful for a couple of miles until I get used to how sharp the brakes are. There is nothing wrong with my own brakes.

Comment: Yes my friend has the same car as mine.